# How can i draw this figure and table?

Tags: diagrams

[image]

Does anybody know how I can DRAW This figures in my WinEdt 9.0 ??
Thank you very much dear my friends.
Best

"Saeed"

Comment: This seem as request `do-it-for-me`.  It will be nice if you show, what you succeed to do so far. And with table typing/setting and drawing picture in LaTeX is independent from editor.

Comment: I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: Hello, Saeed, and welcome to the site! It'd be great if you could make a start and try to show something that you've tried. You might start by googling: tikz node diagram and then, separately, table multirow. As it stands, your question is really two very separate questions, so it might be best to focus your question on just one of your issues.

Comment: Figure 1: use `TikZ` probably. Figure 2: use the `booktabs` and `multirow` packages (or `TikZ` if you really want to draw it).

Comment: For star see ˙Not so short Introduction to LaTeX2e`  (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/?lang=en). Than on SE is lot of examples of table settings etc ...

Comment: Related (user's prior do-it-for-me including identical diagram): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288004/how-can-i-plot-this-figure1-alike-that-and-redudce-the-distance-between-figure.

Answer (score 7):

The first figure can be drawn with Ti*k*Z. The second figure is a table that uses both `\multirow` (from the `multirow` package) and `\multicolumn`.

If you want your figure captions to be put on the left side of your page, use `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \caption{My diagram}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,minimum width=1cm,anchor=south west}]
            \node at (2,4) (goal) {Goal};
            \foreach \x in {1,...,3}
                \node at (\x,0) (a\x) {$A_{\x}$};
            \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \c using int(\x+1)] in {0,...,4}{
                \node at (\x,2) (c\c) {$C_{\c}$};
                \draw (goal.south) -- (c\c.north);
                \foreach \xx in {1,...,3}
                    \draw (c\c.south) -- (a\xx.north);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \caption{My table}
        \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Criteria} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Candidates} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Decision-makers}  \\\hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c}{$C$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$A$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$D_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$D_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$D_3$} \\\hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{$C_1$} & $A_1$ & $MG$ & $G$ & $MG$ \\
            & $A_2$ & $G$ & $G$ & $MG$ \\
            & $A_3$ & $VG$ & $G$ & $F$ \\\hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{$C_2$} & $A_1$ & $G$ & $MG$ & $F$ \\
            & $A_2$ & $VG$ & $VG$ & $VG$ \\
            & $A_3$ & $MG$ & $G$ & $VG$ \\\hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{$C_3$} & $A_1$ & $F$ & $G$ & $G$ \\
            & $A_2$ & $VG$ & $VG$ & $G$ \\
            & $A_3$ & $G$ & $MG$ & $VG$ \\\hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{$C_4$} & $A_1$ & $VG$ & $G$ & $VG$ \\
            & $A_2$ & $VG$ & $VG$ & $VG$ \\
            & $A_3$ & $G$ & $VG$ & $MG$ \\\hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{$C_5$} & $A_1$ & $F$ & $F$ & $F$ \\
            & $A_2$ & $VG$ & $MG$ & $G$ \\
            & $A_3$ & $G$ & $G$ & $MG$ \\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

First figure with `tikz`

**Code**

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{every node/.style={draw,minimum width=1cm}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (c-1) {$C_1$};
\node[anchor=south west] (c-2) at (c-1.south east) {$C_2$};
\node[anchor=south west] (c-3) at (c-2.south east) {$C_3$};
\node[anchor=south west] (c-4) at (c-3.south east) {$C_4$};
\node[anchor=south west] (c-5) at (c-4.south east) {$C_5$}; 

\node [above=1cm,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=7mm] (g) at (c-3.north){Goal};

\node [below=1cm,minimum width=1.5cm] (a-2) at (c-3.south){$A_2$};
\node [anchor=south east,minimum width=1.5cm] (a-1) at (a-2.south west){$A_1$};
\node [anchor=south west,minimum width=1.5cm] (a-3) at (a-2.south east){$A_1$};

\foreach \i in{1,2,3,4,5}
{\draw (g.south)--(c-\i.north);}

\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5}
{\foreach \j in {1,2,3}
{\draw (c-\i.south)--(a-\j.north);}} 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can also use `positioning` library to place nodes.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much from all of dear my friends to solve my problem and answer me.

Comment: Ok now How I can use from codes in paper?

Comment: Other codes in my program are:\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{here}

Comment: and:\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}                                  but I don't know when I add these my codes and other codes, I have an error in running. Please tell me how I can use these two figures in every where of my program.   Best                                                                                                           "Saeed"

Comment: @Saeed Please see [this question and answers](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?s=3|0.6278) for help asking effectively for help. If you are not yet familiar with LaTeX itself, please use the link Zarko provided and read about the basics to get yourself started.